# escaping dash in username

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm having difficulty modifying a postgres user that contains a dash in its name - I've run into this problem several times, but can never find the answer (no matter how much googling I do!).

> osm=# grant all on osm_polygon_view to www-data;
>
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "-"
>
> LINE 1: grant all on osm_polygon_view to www-data;
>
> ```
>                                        ^
> ```

I have tried just about every permutation of escape characters and quotes, and still can't get this to work. I have also encountered this when trying to change www-data password.

Answer (score 68):

Double quotes is what you should use - not single quotes.

> grant all on osm_polygon_view to "www-data";

Comment: Use double quotes to make 'delimited identifiers' - for things like table names or column names, and for user names.

Comment: Just want to add that double quotes was necessary for the object name "aaa-bbb-ccc" but I needed *single* quotes for the value 'xxx-yyy-zzz'. A little confusing, but thats how it worked for me :)